# $G$ is cyclic with order $n$ and generator $a$. Prove that every subgroup of $G$ is generated by $a^k$ where $k$ is uniquely determined divisor of n

Tags: abstract-algebra

I would appreciate if someone can check my work.

Given $G=<a>$ and $|G|=n$.

Let $H<G$ with  $|H|=p$ and $H=<a^k>$. This implies that $(a^k)^p=e$.

Thus $p$ is the smallest integer such that $(a^k)^p=e$.

But $|G|=n$ implies that n is the smallest integer such that $a^n=e$.

This implies $kp=n$. Hence $k$ divides $n$.

Comment: You have to prove first $H$ is cyclic, generated by some power of $a$. Also, the fact that $p$ is the smallest integer s.t. …, doesn't imply (directly) that $kp=n$.

Answer (score 0):

Well you've proven that if $H$ is cyclic, it is generated by an uniquely determined power of the generator of $G$, but you still have to prove that every subgroup of $G$ is cyclic.
Hint: Look at the homomorphism $\phi:\Bbb\to G$, where $\phi(k)=a^k$.